# Float values differs while printing the assigned value and the computed value in C

Tags: c

I could see one issue with GCC Compiler while doing the division operation.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   unsigned char a = 81;
   float value_1 = a / 255.; 
   float value_2 = (float)a / 255.0; 
   printf("%.12f----->%.12f -----> %.12f", value_1, value_2, a/255.);
   return 0;
}
```

**Results:**

```
0.317647069693----->0.317647069693 -----> 0.317647058824
```

I could see that results are differing while printing the assigned values and the computed values at the sixth precision. Why it happens?

Answer (score 7):

The first two values are single-precision floating-point values, and the final one is a double-precision value. If you print them with more decimals you will see the difference, for example like this:

```
0.3176470696926116943359375000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0.3176470696926116943359375000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0.3176470588235293934786795944091863930225372314453125000000000000000000
```

Remember that the standard floating-point type in C is double, not float. A floating-point constant, such as your `255.`, has the type double, not float. So the final argument to printf, `a/255.`, will be calculated using double precision, and sent to printf as a double. The variables `value_1` and `value_2` are of type float, and even though they are converted to double when sent to printf, they have fewer binary digits.

Answer (score 0):

First two are floats while last one is a double. **double** has 2x more precision than **float**.

Single precision (float) gives you 23 bits of significand, 8 bits of exponent, and 1 sign bit.

Double precision (double) gives you 52 bits of significand, 11 bits of exponent, and 1 sign bit.

Comment: The mathematical significands in the common formats used for `float` and `double` are 24 and 53 bits, respectively. The main fields used for encoding the significands are 23 and 52 bits, but another bit is derived from the exponent field.

Comment: Annex F is *optional*, so compilers are allowed to provide non-IEC-60559 floating point (albeit, in practice, almost all are close to conformant).